# Kafka consumer list

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to find out a way to ask Kafka for a list of topics. I know I can do that using the `kafka-topics.sh` script included in the `bin\` directory. Once I have this list, I need all the consumers per topic. I could not find a script in that directory, nor a class in the `kafka-consumer-api` library that allows me to do it.

The reason behind this is that I need to figure out the difference between the topic's offset and the consumers' offsets.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or do I need to implement this functionality in each of my consumers?

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer given that things have changed and zookeeper is not used in newer versions of Kafka.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Use kafka-consumer-groups.sh

For example

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group mygroup --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Comment: we should use --zookeeper not --bootstrap-server

Comment: but 0.9.0.0 is not an ancient version of kafka :)

Comment: bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).

bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use the Java consumer API (non-ZooKeeper-based consumers).

Comment: Consumer group list command lists all the consumers groups in the cluster, but is there a way to show consumer groups for specific topic?

Comment: @user3366706 `kafka-consumer-groups --topic` only applies when providing `--reset-offsets`, so there would have to be a different flag to create an API call for "groups for a specific topic"

Comment: When I execute the list function, I'm getting following error "Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to Request METADATA failed on brokers List"

Answer (score 21):

you can use this for 0.9.0.0. version kafka

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --zookeeper hostname:potnumber
```

to view the groups you have created. This will display all the consumer group names.

```
 ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --zookeeper hostname:potnumber  --describe  --group consumer_group_name
```

To view the details

```
GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER
```

Answer (score 19):

I realize that this question is nearly 4 years old now. Much has changed in Kafka since then. This is mentioned above, but only in small print, so I write this for users who stumble over this question as late as I did.

1. Offsets by default are now stored in a Kafka Topic (not in Zookeeper any more), see [Offsets stored in Zookeeper or Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137281/offsets-stored-in-zookeeper-or-kafka)
2. There's a kafka-consumer-groups utility which returns all the information, including the offset of the topic and partition, of the consumer, and even the lag (Remark: When you ask for the topic's offset, I assume that you mean the offsets of the partitions of the topic). In my Kafka 2.0 test cluster:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --describe
    --group console-consumer-69763 Consumer group 'console-consumer-69763' has no active members.

TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
pytest          0          5               6               1               -               -               -
``
```

Answer (score 16):

**All the consumers per topic**

(Replace `--zookeeper` with `--bootstrap-server` to get groups stored by newer Kafka clients)

Get all consumers-per-topic as a table of `topic`<kbd>tab</kbd>`consumer`:

```
for t in `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper <HOST>:2181 --list 2>/dev/null`; do
    echo $t | xargs -I {} sh -c "kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper <HOST>:2181 --describe --group {} 2>/dev/null | grep ^{} | awk '{print \$2\"\t\"\$1}' "
done > topic-consumer.txt
```

Make this pairs unique:

```
cat topic-consumer.txt | sort -u > topic-consumer-u.txt
```

Get the desired one:

```
less topic-consumer-u.txt | grep -i <TOPIC>
```

Comment: I think this is the closest solution to the asked question. This should be the accepted answer. Sometimes you don't know the consumer groups and that's why you'd need this. The only caveat to that solution is that it does not filter out topics in a consumer group where there is no active consumers. Thank you !

Answer (score 15):

I do not see it mentioned here, but a command that i use often and that helps me to have a **bird's eye view** on all groups, topics, partitions, offsets, lags, consumers, etc

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --all-groups
```

A sample would look like this:

```
GROUP TOPIC PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG CONSUMER-ID HOST CLIENT-ID
Group Topic 2          7               7               0   <SOME-ID>   XXXX <SOME-ID>
:
:
```

The **most important** column is the `LAG`, where for a **healthy** platform, *ideally* it should be `0`(or nearer to 0 or a low number for high throughput) - at all times. So make sure you monitor it!!! ;-).

P.S:
An interesting article on how you can monitor the lag can be found [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/using/monitor-lag.html).

Answer (score 4):

Kafka stores all the information in zookeeper. You can see all the topic related information under **brokers->topics**. If you wish to get all the topics programmatically you can do that using Zookeeper API.

It is explained in detail in below links
[Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/zookeeper/zookeeper_api.htm), [Zookeeper Programmer guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html)

Comment: This is actually incorrect in the newer versions of Kafka. Zookeeper is no longer used to store offsets. The offsets are stored in Kafka itself in specially named topics

Comment: Agree with  Basanth. But anyhow, providing an answer to to stackoverflow should contain enough question-related and useful information to provide a minimal value.

Answer (score 3):

High level consumers are registered into Zookeeper, so you can fetch a list from ZK, similarly to the way `kafka-topics.sh` fetches the list of topics. I don't think there's a way to collect *all* consumers; any application sending in a few consume requests is actually a "consumer", and you cannot tell whether they are done already.

On the consumer side, there's a [JMX metric exposed to monitor the lag](http://docs.confluent.io/1.0.1/kafka/monitoring.html#consumer-metrics). Also, there is [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow) for lag monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [kafkactl](https://github.com/deviceinsight/kafkactl) for this:

```sh
# get all consumer groups (output as yaml)
kafkactl get consumer-groups -o yaml

# get only consumer groups assigned to a single topic (output as table)
kafkactl get consumer-groups --topic topic-a
```

Sample output (e.g. as yaml):

```yaml
name: my-group
protocoltype: consumer
topics:
 - topic-a
 - topic-b
 - topic-c
```

Disclaimer: I am contributor to this project

Answer (score 0):

And another important point, while running below command, if you see `consumer_ID` is empty it means its inactive.

```bash
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --describe  --group promotion1
```

```
GROUP               TOPIC                       PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
promotion1          PromotionBusiness 0          75554           77040           1486            -               -               -         -               -               -
```