# how to get partition info and offset for Kafka topic without knowing consumer group info

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, hadoop-streaming, kafka-topic

I am totally a squat in `Kafka` land 
If I run the command

```
/cfintools/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic $t  --bootstrap-server  $bt  --consumer.config /cfintools/avro_consumer_ssl_cfin_prod.properties --property schema.registry.url=$regd --from-beginning
```

the thing just takes forever to return. No error  but no data either.

All I want is the latest 10 messages in that topic and I read about `partition` and `offsets` . Now I dont know how n the world should I go about getting this info 
Some other place I read about this command

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group count_errors --describe
```

But I dont know my consumer group. I just know a `topic` name and other parameters mentioned in the 1st command 
So with this ltd info how do I get the last 10 odd messages in the topic searching only a specific partition and offset or any other way

I tried to use the `kt` tool

```
$  ./kt topic -brokers $bk -filter $t -partitions -leaders -replicas
failed to create client err=kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
```

I know the brokers are valid because  I m  using them

What I want  most kindly :

- get `partition` and offsets in most straightforward manner without any additional info like consumer group
- Any other approach to automatically search  last 10 `messages` - that partition and offset and fetch
- any GUI based tool that will prevent me from  becoming mad

Comment: If you want to consume from a topic, you have to have a consumer group. If you don't  have any ACL in your cluster you can try `test-consumer-group`

Comment: I guess I am a little ignorant about this so please help me out get me a clear picture so when we r weaving the contents of a topic we do not use the group parameter we need the bootstrap topic name et cetera but with this command (one that ends in from the beginning) I don't know how many partitions are there and they are offsets ( so I can query just that one partition that has the latest data. ) ... show with the same extent of information that is the topic name bootstrap-server and schema registry I wanted to know how I can get the partition name and offset that is what I am trying to get

Comment: if I can run consumer avro command that you just saw it means I should have a consumer group? then how do I find it out

Comment: [this can help you to see consumer groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41645130/5687237) but remember, consumer avro command automatically sets consumer group