# Apache Kafka get list of consumers on a specific topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

As it can be guest from the title, is there a way to get the consumer list on a specific topic in java?
Untill now Im able to get the list of topics like this

```
    final ListTopicsResult listTopicsResult = adminClient.listTopics();
    KafkaFuture<Set<String>> kafkaFuture = listTopicsResult.names();
    Set<String> map = kafkaFuture.get();
```

but I havent found a way to get the list of consumers on each topic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697999/kafka-consumer-list might work for you?

Comment: @Stefan thx for answering, I have already seen it but nothing useful, there are no info about consumers for topic

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was recently solving the same problem for my kafka client tool. It is not easy, but the only way, which I found from the code is the following:

```
Properties props = ...//here you put your properties
AdminClient kafkaClient = AdminClient.create(props);

//Here you get all the consumer groups
List<String> groupIds = kafkaClient.listConsumerGroups().all().get().
                       stream().map(s -> s.groupId()).collect(Collectors.toList()); 

//Here you get all the descriptions for the groups
Map<String, ConsumerGroupDescription> groups = kafkaClient.
                                               describeConsumerGroups(groupIds).all().get();
for (final String groupId : groupIds) {
    ConsumerGroupDescription descr = groups.get(groupId);
    //find if any description is connected to the topic with topicName
    Optional<TopicPartition> tp = descr.members().stream().
                                  map(s -> s.assignment().topicPartitions()).
                                  flatMap(coll -> coll.stream()).
                                  filter(s -> s.topic().equals(topicName)).findAny();
            if (tp.isPresent()) {
                //you found the consumer, so collect the group id somewhere
            }
}
```

This API is available from the version 2.0. There is probably a better way but I was not able to find one. You can also find the code on my [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/JRS/open-gavka/overview)

Answer (score 5):

I am aware that this topic is a bit old, but I'm currently working on a dashboard that needs to list topics with relevant consumer groups.
**Katya's** answer is ok, but it still won't list TopicPartitions for consumer groups without active members.
I came across this solution, hope it helps:

```
Properties props = ...//here you put your properties
AdminClient kafkaClient = AdminClient.create(props);

Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets = kafkaClient
    .listConsumerGroupOffsets("consumer_group_name")
    .partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata()
    .get();
```

TopicPartition in offsets map can be parsed for specific topic. This listing can be repeated for whole groupId list from **Katya's** answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consumers aren't tied to a topic. They are tied to consumer groups

To get all the consumers of a topic, you must first list all groups, then filter out your topic within each group

Which would start with `AdminClient.listConsumerGroups` followed by `AdminClient.describeConsumerGroups`

That gets you a list of descriptions that contain the "members" where you can find the topics

https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/ConsumerGroupDescription.html

Note: there's external tools that make this much easier like Hortonworks SMM https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/SMM/SMM-1.2.0/monitoring-kafka-clusters/content/smm-monitoring-consumers.html