# Figure Out Whether All Messages are Consumed or Not in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new on Kafka. I'll send couple of messages to kafka topic with multiple partitions and I'll consume it. At the end of it, if all related messages are consumed, I'll send a notification.

For example:

Create a topic with `3 partitions`

```
for 1 to n:
   sendItemToKafkaTopic(item-unique-key) 
end
```

then consume it:

`processItem (1 to n)` with scalable system and finally in `n. item` send notification as completed.

Note: producer side should work as concurrently so there won't be a single bulk operation.

Is there any suggestion? BTW, Kafka solution is not necessary. If you have other options, please share.

Comment: You can try to get the high watermark of the topic and last committed offset of the consumer group, which will give you LAG of the topic, if your LAG is 0 then all messages are consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an amazing post about this: https://medium.com/@debyroth340/identify-job-completion-in-multi-phase-kafka-consumers-33ee8a974963

1. Complete producer steps.
2. Take offset snapshot of topic and create a record.
3. Continue consumer processes and take snapshot of consumer offsets.
4. If current offset snapshot is greater than the record, then notify it as completed.

To take snapshot, you can use `AdminClient` in kafka.

```
TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(topicName, 0);
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetSpec> topicPartitionOffsets = Map.of(
       tp,OffsetSpec.latest());
var offsets = adminClient.listOffsets(topicPartitionOffsets);
```

To find consumer-groups: [Apache Kafka get list of consumers on a specific topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937806/apache-kafka-get-list-of-consumers-on-a-specific-topic)
After finding the consumer groups, you can fetch offsets of the consumer groups.