# How to retrieve Kafka Consumer Configs

Tags: apache-kafka

I have several consumers that connect to Kafka Cluster that I do not have control over. At the same time, I would like to have visibility into how those consumers are configured.

Is there an API to list all consumers (if there is one for publishers, it is an added benefit) and then read all their configs?
I am talking about these consumer settings:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#cp-config-consumer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka consumer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697999/kafka-consumer-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as most of those settings are configured at the consumer only and are not pushed to the brokers or any topic.

It's possible however to get a high-level description for a given consumer group:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group consumer-group
```